# What is the version of Silverlight that is implemented in Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I was wondering what version of Silverlight is implemented in the current release of Windows Phone 7?

The reason I want to know is that I want to bind to an indexer that is string-based. This is a newly added feature in Silverlight 4 ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645024%28VS.95%29.aspx#indexdata)) and its not working in Windows Phone 7 and I am trying to figure out if the issue is in my code or with Silverlight on WP7

Comment: Did you find if binding to a indexer[string] is working? I think I have the same issue and the answer does not fully answer the question here.

Comment: No, because at present the version of Silverlight implemented on WP7 is v3, string based indexers are not supported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Silverlight on the phone is Silverlight 3 with some inclusions/exclusions that make sense for the phone platform.

More detail here.

[Differences Between Silverlight on Windows and Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426930%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

[Features Supported in Silverlight for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426931%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

[Class Library Support for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470087%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)